# Can the shell created from PHP shell_exec is reusable?

Tags: shell-exec

I am working on a project, where I need to execute multiple unix script from PHP environment. Could this be possible to open a single unix shell and execute all the unix scripts.

Currently im using shell_exec for each of the scripts execution. This makes the application slow, as each time shell_exec,a new shell is being opened and the script is executed.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

No, the underlying shell is not accessible.

You could try few things:

- Optimise the scripts so you have to do fewer execs. Pipe them or something like that
- I am not sure if it will work but you should be able to start a bash process and send commands to it (see [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)). This way you could be able to manually and reuse the shell. But I imagine it will be a nightmare, especially in parsing the responses from the scripts (if you need that).

Comment: Hi Dimitar, thanks for the quick response. I do need to read the response from the shell. So, will proc_open is advisable to use?